# Kernel is crashing during evaluation of FindRoot

Tags: warning-messages, kernel

I have a bunch of aux functions and constants

```
S=1; ja=0.98; jb=1; jc=0.0004; j2=0.52; d=0.00143; T=0.001

omega [s_, d_, T_, x_, y_, z_] = Sqrt[(2 s (ja - jb + 2 j2 + jb Cos[y] + 
   d theta))^2 - (2 s (ja Cos[x] + jc Cos[z] + 
   2 j2 Cos[x] Cos[y]))^2] // Simplify

theta = 1 - s/(2 S) (1 + 2 F[s, d, T]) // Simplify

F[s_, d_, T_] := 
 1/(2 π)^3 NIntegrate[(
     2 s (ja - jb + 2*j2 + jb*Cos[y] + d*theta))/
     omega[s, d, T, x, y, z] Coth[omega[s, d, T, x, y, z]/
      T], {x, -π/2, π/2}, {y, -π, π}, {z, -π/
      2, π/2}] - 1/2
```

That I pass to the function `m`

```
m[s_, d_, T_] = 1/((1 + F[s, d, T])^(2 S + 1) - F[s, d, T]^(
2 S + 1)) ((S - F[s, d, T]) (1 + F[s, d, T])^(
  2 S + 1) + (S + 1 + F[s, d, T]) F[s, d, T]^(2 S + 1)) // Simplify
```

Later, when I try to use `FindRoot` on it like so:

```
FindRoot[m[s, 0.00143, 0.001] == s, {s, 1}]
```

I get the following error:

> Wolfram Kernel for Windows has stopped working

Any suggestions ?

EDIT:

Crash stops if I define all functions with `:=`. It still takes a very long time to compute and I'm not even sure will it ever give any result.

Comment: Should we guess what are the definitions behind those symbols -- `omega`, `theta`, etc ? Please, include them and format your code and question properly. Try reading it from the perspective of an unfamiliar-with-the-domain person, but still a user of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Might you have forgotten to include the error by any chance ?

Comment: Well it doesn't really give what the error is, it just gives this _Wolfram Kernel for Windows has stopped working_

Comment: You have to read about the differences between `Set` and `SetDelayed`, a good start is this very same *Mathematica*.SE site. Also function definition and passing non-numerical values to `NIntegrate`. All in all I think that should suffice.

Comment: I already have done similar problems with practically same code and function defining and haven't had this kind of error. Btw thanks for editing my question, first time using stackexchange.

Comment: There are two topics here: 1. Finding a solution for the OP. 2. Understanding the crash.  Regardless any mistake of the OP, the kernel should never crash. I think that if a minimal example can reproducibly crash the kernel this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: And the usual warning that functions with capital letters, such as,  `F`, are generally a bad idea as they are often used by mathematica.

Comment: by the way, I don't think is `FindRoot` causing the problem. The evaluation of either `theta`, `F` or `omega` is enough to crash the kernel on my v10.1

Comment: The definitions are circular. `F` depends on `theta` which depends on `F`

Comment: It's not that. I already solved this kind of equations, so I doubt it's that.

Comment: @Djole Are you *really really* sure that the fact that you have a circular definition is not a problem? Can you calculate any values of your auxiliary functions themselves before the `FindRoot`? I mean, if you try to evaluate e.g. `m[s, 0.00143, 0.001]` as shown in your code, do you get any result?

Comment: Well of course I can't be 100% sure, but I had similar problem and it was solvable. Indeed it was somewhat easier because it hadn't had so much terms, but nevertheless it had circular definitions in its "body". I can't compute any function that includes this integral, so no, especially because if you keep `s` as a parameter `NIntegrate` can't work.

Comment: (A) Why do you use `Set` (i.e. the `=` symbol) in function definitions instead of `SetDelayed` (i.e. `:=`)? $$$$
(B) This is probably **not** the source of your problem, but sometimes it is better to define functions with `m[s_?NumericQ...]` as discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

Answer (score 3):

As [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) and [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob) have already mentioned in the comments, the problem appears to be in the circular definition.

Because of the way these are defined, neither `m[s, d, T]` nor `F[s, d, T]` can be evaluated with numerical values of `s, d` and `T`, so there isn't much `FindRoot` could do.

A simplified example might be

```
 f[s_] := NIntegrate[f[s], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]                         

 f[1]

 (* Segmentation fault (core dumped) *)
```

`NIntegrate` should ideally fail in a more graceful way, but I do not see the point of trying to evaluate this input.